# Creating a plagiarism detector using python

Tags: python

Good day. I am trying to create a plagiarism detector using python, by comparing the text of two files and return the similar phrase that has at least 5 words. when i run the code below I got the following Index Error: list index out of range... Here is my code and the three text documents;

```
def check_plagiarism(file1, file2):
with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
    with open(file2, 'r') as f2:
        f1_content = f1.read().split(' ')
        f2_content = f2.read().split(' ')
        longest_series = []

        for i, word in enumerate(f1_content):
            if word in f2_content:

                word_indexes = []
                curr_index = 0
                searching = True

                while searching is True:
                    if word in f2_content[curr_index:]:
                        word_indexes.append(f2_content[curr_index:].index(word) + curr_index)
                        curr_index = word_indexes[-1] + 1
                    else:
                        searching = False

                for ind in word_indexes:
                    j = 0

                    while i + j < len(f1_content):
                        if f1_content[i+j] != f2_content[ind+j]:
                            break
                        current_series = f1_content[i:i + j + 1]

                        if len(current_series) > len(longest_series):
                            longest_series = current_series
                        j += 1

if len(longest_series) < 5:
    return False
else:
    return ' '.join(longest_series)

print(check_plagiarism("file_4.txt", "file_5.txt"))
print(check_plagiarism("file_4.txt", "file_6.txt"))
print(check_plagiarism("file_5.txt", "file_6.txt"))
```

file_4.txt: (ejaculate risen campanile metazoa inexpedient chaise tuple storytelling bursty longevity smithereens necromancy middle provenance moccasin paw trailside signify hoagie sturgeon bartok procaine crocodilian leftward gallup protista laughter ucla dateline imprecise pungent episcopate dyestuff melanoma showpiece canine marie inlay alabama stubby lass contrive cationic wasnt seam rosenberg legacy q crevice hysterectomy consumptive palaeontology insipid sap)

file_5.txt: (ejaculate risen campanile metazoa beaujolais sorb quasiparticle hair somalia teach turnaround firsthand hough penury daemon felt cat heterodyne pinwheel wasnt seam rosenberg legacy q crevice hysterectomy consumptive palaeontology insipid sap)

file_6.txt: (pungent episcopate dyestuff melanoma showpiece canine marie inlay alabama stubby lass contrive cationic luzon superlative kirkland farmland ejaculate risen campanile metazoa wink humorous judith cpa chromosomal electrophorus like groom insistent passe wingbeat ferdinand spume inexpedient chaise tuple storytelling bursty longevity smithereens)

Thank you for your time and effort..

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: The work of isolating a [mre] with the shortest possible code and data that reproduces a specific issue is part of the process of asking a question. Ideally, that question should focus on the problem itself, rather than on what you were trying to do when you encountered it -- unless those are entirely inextricable.

Comment: I just wanted to find out why i have got that "index out of range" error each time i try to run the code. I am trying to detect 5 successive words or more that found in both files, else, the function will return False. the two text files are located at my local server (Personal work station). .... Thank you